# how to safely call queries as strings inside other functions in codeigniter php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am using codeigniter, and I have multiple queries that I have written inside seperate public functions. I would like to then use each of these queries and call them as strings inside another query to process them.

Here is what I mean

```
public function first_of_many_queries(){

    $query = "  
                SELECT *
                FROM users
                WHERE id = $id 
                AND   age = $age 
                AND   gender = $gender 
                ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1 
            ";

    return $this->db->escape_str($this->handeling_all_queries($query, 1));

}    

public function handeling_all_queries($qry, $type){

    $query = $this->db->query($qry);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        //doo stuff
    }

}
```

**My question is**

Is this safe practice? is the use of `$this->db->escape_str($this->handeling_all_queries($query, 1))` enough to prevent sql injection and other problems?

THANKS

Comment: I see you've already asked two questions about binding. You're not ignorant. So, no it's not safe, and your code seems untested and invalid. Better read a good tutorial first.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - could you please point me in the right direction? I have read many of the documents supplied by code igniter and read many forums, but no one covers such topics. I have been looking for multiple days, and I still can't progress in my search, hence asking twice :(

Comment: Well, to have a change for a query to be safe you will have to use binding, instead of inserting PHP variables directly into the query string. So you cannot build a complete query string, with inserted variables, inside a function like you intend.

Comment: I shouldn't say this, but in some exceptional circumstances, where you are absolutely in control of the value of a variable, you could insert it directly into a query string. (don't tell anyone: I didn't say this!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is not at all safe. You can use Query Binding in Codeigniter.

> Binding queries is another useful security process; if you use binding
>   with your queries, values are automatically escaped by CodeIgniter,
>   and there is no need for you to manually do so.
>
> ```
> $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND age = ? AND gender = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
> $this->db->query($query, $id, $age , $gender);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not use the query string in the second query (as a string) if I find it in the first query. Please look at the question again thanks for your answer

Comment: So you basically want to secure or escape the raw queries whcih are wirtten in various functions through a common function which can escape them. The option left for you is too escape variables in each query manually. Eg: `$sql = "SELECT *from users  WHERE id = '".$this->db->escape_str($id)."' AND age ='".$this->db->escape_str($age)."' AND gender = '".$this->db->escape_str($gender)."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";`

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe. Use PDO prepared statements for safe queries:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND age = ? AND gender = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
$stmt->execute([$id, $age, $gender]);
```

Comment: Please *elaborate* an answer when giving one. Use links **only** to provide references rather than basing the entire answer on the links alone.

Comment: Thanks, but Im not asking how to bind queries. I'm asking if I can escape query strings in one query, then call it in another, using codeigntier's  `$this->db->escape_str`